# javax.naming.NoInitialContextException:

Tags: java, jms

Estou tentando fazer um trabalho da universidade com messageria, mas o meu chat não está iniciando e apresentando o seguinte problema:

```
  javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory]
    C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: -1
```

Porque acontece esse problema?

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package autoinstrucionalclientprj;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.QueueReceiver;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.jms.Topic;
import javax.jms.TopicConnection;
import javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.TopicSession;
import javax.jms.TopicSubscriber;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
/**
 *
 * @author Gabriel
 */
public class Client extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Server
     */
    public Client() {
        initComponents();
    }
   private String usuario;
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        btnEnviar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        txtMensagem = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtDestinatario = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtMensagens = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txtMensagensRecebidas = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        lblCodigoDestinatario = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lblMensagem = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtCodigoUsuario = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        lblCodigoUsuario = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                formWindowOpened(evt);
            }
        });

        btnEnviar.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Gabriel\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\AutoInstrucionalClientPrj\\icons\\email-send-icon.png")); // NOI18N
        btnEnviar.setText("Enviar");
        btnEnviar.setName("btnEnviar"); // NOI18N
        btnEnviar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnEnviarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        txtMensagem.setName("txtMensagem"); // NOI18N
        txtMensagem.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                txtMensagemKeyPressed(evt);
            }
        });

        txtDestinatario.setName(""); // NOI18N

        txtMensagensRecebidas.setEditable(false);
        txtMensagensRecebidas.setColumns(20);
        txtMensagensRecebidas.setRows(5);
        txtMensagensRecebidas.setEnabled(false);
        txtMensagens.setViewportView(txtMensagensRecebidas);

        lblCodigoDestinatario.setText("Código do Destinatário: ");

        lblMensagem.setText("Mensagem: ");

        txtCodigoUsuario.setEditable(false);
        txtCodigoUsuario.setEnabled(false);

        lblCodigoUsuario.setText("O seu código é :");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(txtMensagens)
                        .addContainerGap())
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(lblCodigoDestinatario)
                            .addComponent(lblMensagem))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(txtDestinatario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 126, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addContainerGap())
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(txtMensagem, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 336, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(btnEnviar)
                                .addGap(19, 19, 19))))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(lblCodigoUsuario)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(txtCodigoUsuario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 226, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(txtCodigoUsuario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(lblCodigoUsuario))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(txtMensagens, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 376, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(txtDestinatario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 26, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(lblCodigoDestinatario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(btnEnviar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 53, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(txtMensagem, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 53, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(lblMensagem)))
                .addGap(22, 22, 22))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
        String palavra;

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        //gera uma palavra randomica
        palavra = PalavraRandomica.nomeAleatorio(10);

        //concatena o ano, mes e dia com a palavra a randomica para gerar o nome de um usuario
        txtCodigoUsuario.setText(String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.YEAR)) + String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MONTH)) + String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))  + palavra);

        usuario = txtCodigoUsuario.getText();
        if(usuario != null && !usuario.equals("")){
            topicos();
            filas();
        }else{
            System.exit(0);
        }




    }                                 

    private void btnEnviarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        enviarMensagem();
    }                                         

    private void txtMensagemKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        }
    }                                      

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Client().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }


    private void topicos(){
        Context context = initContext();
        TopicConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
        Topic topic = null;
        try{
            connectionFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) context.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
            topic = (Topic) context.lookup("TesteTopic");
        }catch(NamingException nex){
            alertDialog("Impossível se conectar!" );
            alertDialog("Exceção gerada: " + nex);
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        TopicConnection connection = null; //Criando a conexão e a sessão
        try{
            connection = connectionFactory.createTopicConnection();
            TopicSession session = connection.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            TopicSubscriber subscriber = session.createSubscriber(topic);
            subscriber.setMessageListener(new Mensagens());
            connection.start();
        }catch(JMSException jex){
            alertDialog("Impossível de se conectar");
            System.out.println("Exceção gerada" + jex);
        }
    }


     private void filas(){

        Context context = initContext();       

        QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;  // Cconexões da fábrica e da fila de destino
        Queue queue = null;
        try {
            connectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup("ConnectionFactory");//pesquisa conexão
            queue = (Queue) context.lookup("TesteQueue");//pesquisa o serviço
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        QueueConnection connection = null;
        try {// Criando a conexão e da sessão
            connection = connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();

            //false => não utiliza transação)
            QueueSession session = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            String codigoUsuariio = "KEY='" + usuario + "'";

            QueueReceiver receiver = session.createReceiver(queue, usuario); //passa a fila e a "senha" - nome do usuario        

            receiver.setMessageListener(new Mensagens());
            connection.start();

        } catch (JMSException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
     private void alertDialog(String message){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, "Bate Papo", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

    //init context
    private Context initContext(){
        Context initContext = null;
        try{
            initContext = new InitialContext();
        }catch(NamingException nex)
        {
            System.err.println("Impossível de receber contexto: " + nex);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        return initContext;
    }

    //envia a mensagem
    private void enviarMensagem(){
        String usuarioEspecifico = txtCodigoUsuario.getText().trim();
        String mensagem = txtMensagem.getText().trim();
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
        if(usuarioEspecifico.equals("")){

            sendMessage.sendMessage(initContext(),usuarioEspecifico, mensagem);
        }
        else{
            txtMensagensRecebidas.setText(txtMensagensRecebidas.getText() + usuarioEspecifico + ": " + mensagem + "\n");
            sendMessage.sendMessage(initContext(),usuario, mensagem, usuarioEspecifico);
        }

        txtMensagem.setText("");
    }
    private void inserirMensagem(String messageObj){
        String[] messageInfos = messageObj.split(";");

        String nomeUsuario = messageInfos[0];
        String mensagem = messageInfos[1];

        String previousMessage = txtMensagensRecebidas.getText();  
        txtMensagensRecebidas.setText(previousMessage + nomeUsuario + ": " + mensagem + "\n\n"); // aparece ex.: Tata: Oi!

        txtMensagem.setText("");//esvazia a caixa de texto
    }
    private class Mensagens implements MessageListener {
        @Override
        public void onMessage(Message message){
            try{
                if(message == null){
                    alertDialog("Falha no recebimento de mensagem!");
                }
                else if(message instanceof TextMessage){
                    TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage)message;
                    String msg = textMessage.getText();
                    inserirMensagem(msg);
                }
                else{
                    alertDialog("Erro ao receber mensagens!");
                }
            }catch(JMSException jmex){
                alertDialog(jmex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnEnviar;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblCodigoDestinatario;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblCodigoUsuario;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblMensagem;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtCodigoUsuario;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtDestinatario;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtMensagem;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane txtMensagens;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea txtMensagensRecebidas;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

```
java.naming.factory.initial = org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
# use the following property to embed a broker inside this JVM
#useEmbeddedBroker = true

# use the following property to specify a class path resource or URL
# used to configure an embedded broker using the XML configuration file
#brokerXmlConfig = file:src/conf/sample-conf/default.xml

# use the following property to configure the default connector
brokerURL = tcp://localhost:61616 

# use the following property to specify the JNDI name the connection factory
# should appear as. 
#connectionFactoryNames = connectionFactory, queueConnectionFactory, topicConnectionFactry

# register some queues in JNDI using the form
# queue.[jndiName] = [physicalName]
queue.TesteQueue = TesteQueue

# register some topics in JNDI using the form
# topic.[jndiName] = [physicalName]
topic.TesteTopic = TesteTopic
```

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory]
```

A princípio parece que você está sem a lib dessa classe no seu classpath. Adicionar as dependencias abaixo no seu pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
    <version>5.15.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
     <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
     <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Move o seu arquivo de propriedades para a pasta ***src/main/resources***. Com isso deve funcionar.

Comment: Amigão, vou testar isso do que você havia me falado

Essa pasta fica dentro do projeto netbeans? Não encontrei ela

Comment: @gabrielfalieri se você está usando maven, essa pasta é criada automaticamente pelo Netbeans quando você cria o projeto.